# What instead C# .NET? But without needed framework installation by user.

Tags: c#, .net, qt, frameworks

I want to move my application from C# .NET to some other lsnguage that doesn't need a framework setup but has easy GUI creating and can call a webserver and get a response.

I was thinking about C++/Qt. What about that?

Comment: Part of the benefit of that framework is that you get to have the features of easy GUIs and http communication.

Comment: This depends on your platform. 

If you for instance say that Windows 7 is your platform it happens that .NET3.5 is preinstalled with Windows 7 thus no need for installers if you stay on .NET3.5.

If you have to target say Linux, OSX and Windows then you are problably looking a C/C++ + something.

So what platforms are you targeting? Chose what tools are available on those platform out of the box or that can be deployed with minimal problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you purchase a commercial Mono license, you can embed the .NET runtime into your application.

Porting to another language would be quite troublesome and difficult, but can be done. Just expect a lot of hard work.

C++/Qt will work, but it is different, and you'll need to manage with memory management, which .NET does for you.

I'd suggest you look at Delphi. It has similar classes to .NET, but is native.

**PS**. What is the rationale for moving to another language without the framework? Why is getting the user (or you installing it as part of the installation process) infeasible?

Comment: Thats a game launcher. Players have problems with .NET Framework setup etc. I dont like Delphi syntax, is C++ Builder also native?

Comment: C++ is also native. You still won't get the level of classes that you'll get in .NET, but its worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just say this straight away: C++ and Qt make a *great* pair - but they take getting used to.

Developing C++ apps is entirely different from developing managed apps. For one, C++ required the developer to manage memory. Also, C++ is a *much* more complicated language, and things tend to be done in an *entirely* different way than higher-level language (even though ty do support man of the same concepts).

I don't mean to deter the switch to C++ (or to any other language), I just want to make it clear that this is a decision that only *you* can make, and advice is hard to give with the current level of information from you. The value of a language and GUI framework depends entirely on the types of things you wish to accomplish, which paradigms you want to work within, and which platforms you'd like to develop for.

But, as far as options go, here's a couple known routes:

1. C++

   - Qt
   - wxWidgets
   - gtkmm
   - MFC
2. Python

   - PyQt
   - PyGtk
   - wxPyhton
   - See more [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)
3. Java

   - JFC
   - SWT
4. D (not used by many people, but why not?)

   - Most of C++ should apply
   - Check [this list](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?GuiLibraries) out
5. Any other language

   - Just Google the language name along with "GUI programming" or something, and you'll get answers.

Of course, there's many, *many* other choices, so use your friend called Google.

Answer (score 1):

No offense but it sounds like you want the moon :)

If you want / need a GUI framework / library then you're going to have to accept some trade offs.

.Net and Java offer some very easy to generate GUIs but these frameworks require installation.

qT, wxWidgets and a few other libraries offer a zero-installation experience with using a GUI but require more work and a different language to use.

So where do you want to spend your time? If you need something up and running quickly, you need to use a rapid application development framework like .Net or Java. If you have quite a bit of time or this is a personal project, then using something like qT or wxWidgets may work for you.

It's all about trade-offs.